# How to show YouTube settings menu with custom button?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I want to show YouTube settings menu with custom button, how can i do that?

Code:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((obj, sender, response) => {
  const { type, value, videoId } = obj;

  if (type === 'UPPER') {
    const upper = document.querySelector('.ytp-settings-menu');
    upper.style.removeProperty('display');
  }
});
```